# Changing link content on mouse press in JQuery by html()

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, switch-statement

Good day! For this example of function html() http://api.jquery.com/html/ How to return to link they first look, after next clicking?

like doing when use "scroll down" link, after pressing it changing to "scroll up" (show switch to hide) and all this continued in case of clicking.

if use code like this

```
    <p>scroll down</p>
<script>
    $("p").click(function () {
      var htmlStr = $(this).html();
      $(this).html('scroll up');
    });
</script>
```

in this example assigned last value.

Comment: Sorry, your question is very unclear. If necessary, try writing your question in your native language and use a translator like [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, this is one way to do it:

```
window.textIndex = 1;
window.texts = [ "Scroll Up", "Scroll Down" ];
$("p").click(function () {
    textIndex = 1 - textIndex;
    $(this).html(texts[textIndex]);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for `.toggle()`?

```
$('p').toggle(function(){
  $(this).html('scroll up');
}, function(){
  $(this).html('scroll down');
});
```

[**Example on JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tmtJc/)

Comment: Probably more like a .toggle() inside a .click() event handler.

Comment: That's exactly what this does ;)

Comment: Nice, I didn't know .toggle() could be used that way.  // edit: I didn't even know there were two different `.toggle()`s!

Comment: Yes, it's works)) in a .click() event `<p>scroll down</p>
<script>
    $("p").click(function () {
   $('p').toggle(function(){
    $(this).html('scroll down');
    }, function(){
     $(this).html('scroll up');
   });
  
      var htmlStr = $(this).html();
      $(this).html('scroll up');
    });
</script>`